# Execute script and show output/progress in view [Ruby/Sinatra(Rails)]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, sinatra

I have a deploy script that is called from a helper in my Sinatra app.

I want show a "deploying" view/page, then exec the script.

Then when the script is finished, show a new page with text box with the script output in.

How can this be done?

```
# update.rb - the main app
helpers do
  def run_update
    command = "./script.sh"
    @ok = system( command )
  end
end

post '/version' do
  run_update     # putting this after the erb call doesnt fix it!?
  erb :version
end
```

Currently it hangs after the post is made from the main page. Then when the script is finished it displays the version.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output to a file and display the file over HTTP and keep refreshing the page every x seconds

```
get '/progress' do # This page should be refreshed every x seconds

  # render the file here

end
```

Comment: I like the redirect to file... but could you provide more detail on (1) how the page would get automatically get refreshed? and (2) how I would render the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was looking for was [IO#popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen)

> Runs the specified command as a subprocess; the subprocess’s standard
>   input and output will be connected to the returned IO object.